# get input and pass it as a variable inside the same form

Tags: php, forms, variables, get

I'm sorry for the stupid question but I'm still quite new to php and it's now very very late....

I'm trying to pass an input as part of a form submission inside a php echo (a quantity value as a "data quantity") and I can't quite seem to get it right... can someone please tell me where I'm going wrong... I've tried to get the value but just don't seem to be able to do it... do I need to do some sort of validation first? I'm just really confused at this point...

```
  $form = '<form><input type="number" name="quantity" min="1" value="1">
    <button type="submit" data-quantity="'.isset($_GET["quantity"].'" data-product_id="'.$_product->id.'"
        class="button alt ajax_add_to_cart add_to_cart_button product_type_simple">add to basket</button></form>';
```

It's for a custom quantity add in woocommerce - it's because the usual filter isn't compatible with the plugin so I figured this was the next best thing... it works if I manually add a value into data-quantity... thanks for any help in advance !

full file is here: http://pastie.org/10815844#211-215

Answer (score 0):

Set the quantity outside of the form and if it isn't set in the GET array - this defaults to a quantity of 1.

However on looking at the question again  - you will need to use the same value in the input - or alternatively on hte onclick of the submit butt on either use javascript to determine the value of the quantity input or simply let the form submit and use the POST or GET array on the next page to get hte quantity value (note that you do not have an action or method for the form either.

```
if(isset($_GET["quantity"])){$qty=$_GET["quantity"]}else{$qty=1};

$form = '<form><input type="number" name="quantity" min="1" value="' . $qty . '">
    <button type="submit" data-quantity="'. $qty .'" data-product_id="'.$_product->id.'"
        class="button alt ajax_add_to_cart add_to_cart_button product_type_simple">add to basket</button></form>';
```

Comment: hey - thanks for the reply - that just seems to break the plugin for some reason... I'm not sure if I'm doing this properly... I'd post the entire file but it's 250 lines long...

Comment: looking at your product_id section, does this have to be $_quantity->$qty

Comment: I'm not entirely sure to be honest. Essentially it's a product display slider for upsells. It concatenates a LOT, and this bit is within part of that concatenation... if I remove the quantity setting outside of the form it displays (albeit with a blank quantity for obvious reasons) but when I put that back in above the form it breaks it...

Comment: in case you get a chance to look I've updated the main post with the full file in a link - the problem is between lines 211 and 215...

Comment: looked at it - remembered that I hate wordpress :) - two thoughts - first I cant see where slider_gallery is actually defined - it is concateneated to right from the start of that file (line 5) but I cant see the start of it. Secondly - this line "$_product = new WC_Product( $wa_post->ID );" would infer that it is creating a new $_product, so you will probbly have to reference that to get the quantity. Sorry I couldnt help you more - Good luck with it